# Increasing the font-size of a link using :hover causes a flicker in Firefox. Why?

Tags: css, firefox, hover, font-size

The issue in question can be found here: http://www.test.terribleobject.com/breathing-stillness/

The third link in the menu flickers when moused over. I assume it has to do with the line breaking because this menu item is so long, but I can't find a solution right now.

The problem isn't evident in Chrome.

I'm using a Mac and the most recent FF.

Here is the css:

```
.menu-item a {
      background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #FEFEFE;
      border: 1px solid #103A02;
      border-radius: 5px 50px 5px 5px;
      font-family: 'IM Fell English SC';
      font-size: 1.3em;
      padding: 0 20px 0 10px;
      text-decoration: none;
      text-transform: lowercase;
    }

    .menu-item a:hover {
      background: #999;
      color: #fefefe;
      padding-left: 15px;
      font-size: 1.4em;
    }
```

Thanks for your help. I have a feeling the answer is pretty obvious.

Comment: gah XD you keep changing it. XD  can you go back to where they had varying widths?

Comment: sorry, I didn't realize you all would answer so fast!

Answer (score 2):

The menu items are not large enough to accommodate the text when you hover.

You should

1. increase the `width` of the menu items
2. reduce the `font-size` change (say from `1.4em` to `1.35em`)
3. add a right `margin`

Even better, you should scrap the `font-size` change and instead change the `background-color` and the text color only.

Fyi, I tested this in Chrome and it breaks the layout too.

Answer (score 0):

The flickering is almost certainly comes from the fact that the different font sizes trigger/untrigger the `:hover` effect. I suggest you don't change the font size on hover, and move to a more subtle change such as boldness or color change

Answer (score 0):

Don't change the font-size when hover, change the color instead. The whole part enlarge when the mouseover

Comment: Thank you. But I am looking for a technical solution, not an aesthetic change.